# Questions regarding the proof of the Ram-Rel identity in Ash's Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading the proof of the "Ram-Rel-Identity" in Robert B. Ash's [Algebraic Number Theory](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/ANT.html) (see Chapter 4) and there are a couple of points I'm not understanding. The setup is as follows. $A$ is a Dedekind domain with fraction field $K$, $L$ is a finite, separable extension of $K$ of degree $n$, and $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $A$ and let $PB = \prod_{i=1}^{g}P_i^{e_i}$ be the prime factorization of $P$ as an ideal in $B$. Denote by $f_i$ the dimension of the finite extension $B/P_i$ over $A/P$. Then the Ram-Rel-identity, and the (first part of) its proof, is as follows.

> **4.1.6 Ram-Rel Identity**
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{g}e_if_i=[B/PB : A/P] = \dots$$
>
> *Proof:* To prove the first equality, consider the chain of ideals $$ \begin{align}B &\supseteq P_1 \supseteq P_1^2 \supseteq \cdots
>  \supseteq P_1^{e_1} \\ &\supseteq P_1^{e_1}P_2 \supseteq
>  P_1^{e_1}P_2^2 \supseteq \cdots \supseteq P_1^{e_1}P_2^{e_2} \\
>  &\supseteq \cdots \supseteq P_1^{e_1} \cdots P_g^{e_g} = PB 
>  \end{align} $$ By unique factorization, there can be no ideal between
> the consecutive terms in the sequence. (...) Thus the quotient
> $\beta/\beta P_i$ of any two consecutive terms is a one-dimensional
> vector space over $B/P_i$, as there are no nontrivial proper
> subspaces. (**It is a vector space over this because it is annihilated
> by $P_i$**). But, with notation as in (4.1.5), $[B/P_i : A/P] = f_i$, so
> $[\beta/\beta P_i : A/P] = f_i$. For each $i$, we have exactly $e_i$
> consecutive quotients, each of dimension $f_i$ over $A/P$.
> **Consequently, $[\beta/\beta PB : A/P] = \sum_{i=1}^ge_if_i$, as claimed**.

I have two questions regarding this proof (one minor and one major), both highlighted in bold.

- (Minor) Why does the parenthetical statement imply that it is a vector space?
- (Major) Why does this sum follow? I'm not able to see how all the preceding statements imply this *sum* (intuitively I was thinking that a *product* would show up, as is the case when dealing with the dimensions of tower of fields $F \subseteq E \subseteq K$, and where $[K:F] = [K:E][E:F]$). Could you please give a detailed explanation of how to derive the sum from the preceding statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, note that in general if $P_i$ is an ideal in $B$, then a $B/P_i$-module $M$ is the same thing as a $B$-module $M$ such that $P_iM=0$. When $P_i$ is a maximal ideal, a $B/P$-module is also called a $B/P$-vector space.

For the second one, the basic example you should have in mind is rather that $\dim U/V + \dim V = \dim U$ if $V\subset U$ is a subspace. And more generally if $U\supseteq V_0\supseteq V_1 \supseteq \dots \supseteq V_n = 0$ is a filtration of vector subspaces, then $\dim U = \sum \dim (V_i/V_{i+1})$.

Maybe it is clearer if you take the quotient by $PB$: you have a filtration of $A/P$-vector spaces
$$ \begin{align}B/PB &\supseteq P_1/PB \supseteq P_1^2/PB \supseteq \cdots
 \supseteq P_1^{e_1}/PB \\ &\supseteq P_1^{e_1}P_2/PB \supseteq
 P_1^{e_1}P_2^2/PB \supseteq \cdots \supseteq P_1^{e_1}P_2^{e_2}/PB \\
 &\supseteq \cdots \supseteq P_1^{e_1}/PB \cdots P_g^{e_g}/PB = 0 
 \end{align} $$

Now each successive quotient has dimension $1$ over some $B/P_i$, and therefore has dimension $f_i$ over $A/P$. Since there are $e_i$ terms like this for each $i$, you find the expected sum.